# Find difference between two products based on date

Tags: sql-server

I currently have a table (prediction) with the first column containing two types of data, actual and a forecast. I want to find the difference based on the month between the two forecasts. The table looks like this:

```
Data     | Product |    Forecast M1 | Forecast M2 | Forecast M3
Actual        A              13          16             18
Actual        B              22          24             30
Forecast      A              15          14             21
Forecast      B              24          25             26
```

I want to query a table that compares the two products based on the month to show the absolute value of the difference between the actual and the forecast to look like this:

```
Product |    M1 difference | M2 difference | M3 difference
A              2                  2              3
B              2                  1              4
```

Is this a simple query or does a new table need to be created?

Comment: Do you only have 3 columns named M1 to M3 or is that just an example?

Comment: This is just an example, there are actually 24 columns for 2 years of data.

Comment: Since you have many columns and I would wager that number will increase as more time passes, `dynamic sql` may be the way to go as you will need to call `ABS( )`on the difference of the two row values for each column.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option using a self `join` and `abs`:

```
select t1.product,
       abs(t1.forecastm1 - t2.forecastm1) as m1difference,
       abs(t1.forecastm2 - t2.forecastm2) as m2difference,
       abs(t1.forecastm3 - t2.forecastm3) as m3difference
from prediction t1
    join prediction t2 on t1.product = t2.product
where t1.data = 'Actual' 
    and t2.data = 'Forecast'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query like this:

```
SELECT act.Product
     , act.M1 - forc.M1 AS M1Diff
     , act.M2 - forc.M2 AS M2Diff
     , act.M3 - forc.M3 AS M3Diff
FROM #notnormal AS act
    INNER JOIN #notnormal AS forc ON forc.Product = act.Product
                                     AND act.Data = 'Actual'
                                     AND forc.Data = 'Forecast';
```

Here's the schema I set up to show it:

```
CREATE TABLE #notnormal
(
    Data VARCHAR(10)
  , Product CHAR(1)
  , M1 SMALLINT
  , M2 SMALLINT
  , M3 SMALLINT
);
INSERT INTO #notnormal
(
    Data
  , Product
  , M1
  , M2
  , M3
)
VALUES
('Actual', 'A', 13, 16, 18)
, ('Actual', 'B', 22, 24, 30)
, ('Forecast', 'A', 15, 14, 21)
, ('Forecast', 'B', 24, 25, 26);
```